# Where is the product list page in magento blank theme

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, product-list

Hi I am building a theme based on magento blank theme . However I could not find any Product Listing page displaying a group of products with same categories.
Where could I find the code or Do I need to build it from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the default product list page in the below directory:

**Magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates**

If you want to override the product list page according to your custom design, follow the below steps as per the [referenced](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html):

First, create the below directory in your custom theme:

**magento\app\design\frontend\Vender Name\Theme\Magento_Catalog\templates**

After that copy all the files from `Magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates` and paste in the `magento\app\design\frontend\Vender Name\Theme\Magento_Catalog\templates`

After that run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Hope this help!!!!.

Comment: Thanks!!! but how can I make a URL can direct people to those templates?
And How can I make an same category product List Page? Do I need a extra module?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a module in your custom theme. But if you are using luma theme as a parent theme than you can follow the above steps. For redirect people on those template you can show categories list in you `header.phtml` using CMS block or you can get Category tree (`$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();`).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below directory to get default product list page in Magento 2,

```
magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product
```

f you want the change to be effective in product list page then you have to make a custom theme to override default product list page, please create the below directories:

```
magento2\app\design\frontend\Vender Name\Theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product
```

After creating the directories, copy files from default magento module(module-catalog) and paste in created directories.